# Problem with Kotlin Firebase RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment

Im trying to make a user recyclerview in a fragment, but i can't make it to work.

The idea is to get the users from the database (except for the actual user loged in) and add the user data to the list. The problem is that the list doesn't even apear.

I don't know much about Kotlin, i've recently started and Im struggling with this. Also I don't know where the problem is.

If you need the XML, ask for it

**My Fragment:**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.*


@Suppress("NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS")
class UsersFragment:Fragment(R.layout.fragment_users) {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapterUsers: AdapterUsers
    private lateinit var userList: MutableList<ModelUsers>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Users"
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false)

    userList = ArrayList()

    getAllUsers()

    adapterUsers = AdapterUsers(context!!, userList)

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.users_recyclerView)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapterUsers

    return view
}

private fun getAllUsers() {
    val fUser: FirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    val ref: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

    ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("FUNCTION", "ENTER")
            userList.clear()
            for(ds: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                val modelUsers: ModelUsers? = ds.getValue(ModelUsers::class.java)

                if(!modelUsers?.uid.equals(fUser.uid)){
                    userList.add(modelUsers!!)
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "IN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): ProfileFragment {
        return ProfileFragment()
    }}}
```

**My Custom Adapter:**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import java.lang.Exception

open class AdapterUsers(private var context:Context, private var userList: MutableList<ModelUsers> = mutableListOf<ModelUsers>()): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterUsers.UserViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_users, parent, false)
        return UserViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val userImage = userList[position].image
        val userName = userList[position].name
        val userEmail = userList[position].email

        holder.mNameTv.text = userName
        holder.mEmailTv.text = userEmail
        try {
            Picasso.get().load(userImage).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_image_color).into(holder.mAvatarIv)
        }
        catch (e: Exception){

        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(context, userEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    inner class UserViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val mAvatarIv: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatarIv)
        val mNameTv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTv)
        val mEmailTv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailTv)
    }
}
```

**Model for Users:**

```
data class ModelUsers(
var name: String? = null,
var email: String? = null,
var search: String? = null,
var phone: String? = null,
var image: String? = null,
var cover: String? = null,
var uid: String? = null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refresh your recycler view adapter after your data have changed, try to change your code like this:

```
class UsersFragment:Fragment(R.layout.fragment_users) {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    
    private var userList = mutableListOf<ModelUsers>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Users"
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false)

        recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.users_recyclerView).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            adapter = AdapterUsers(requireContext(), mutableListOf())
        }

        getAllUsers()

        return view
    }

    private fun getAllUsers() {
        val fUser: FirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val ref: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

        ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("FUNCTION", "ENTER")
                userList.clear()

                for(ds: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val modelUsers: ModelUsers? = ds.getValue(ModelUsers::class.java)

                    if(!modelUsers?.uid.equals(fUser.uid)){
                        userList.add(modelUsers!!)
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "IN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                    recyclerView.adapter = AdapterUsers(requireContext(), userList)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): ProfileFragment {
            return ProfileFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you, really really thank you. You actually saved me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use your adapter the list is empty, then maybe 0.2 seconds later, you have fetched the users from the database and populated the list, but the adapter doesn't know the list has changed. After you have populated the list you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter to let it know the list has changed.